Free evolution of coherent states
Is there a closed formula to express the time evolution of coherent states in absence of the potential term (only kinetic energy)?
The coherent state $|\alpha \rangle$ is defined by
$$\hat a|\alpha \rangle = \alpha |\alpha\rangle.$$
The hamiltonian operator $\hat H$ is
$$\hat H = \frac{\hat p^2}{2},$$
and the time evolved coherent state is
$$|\alpha,t \rangle = e^{-i\hat H t} |\alpha\rangle.$$
Is there a closed formula to express $\langle \beta|\alpha,t \rangle $, where $|\beta\rangle$ is a coherent state?
I guess it would involve squeezed states, but did not find the answer in the literature...

You don't say what $\beta$ is, so that part of the question is meaningless. Please clarify!

@JosBergervoet In this context I think it safe to assume that $\beta$ is a complex number and $|\beta\rangle$ is the coherent state (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state) associated with this number.

It's indeed the most likely interpretation (but we should avoid questions full of undefined variables, because they lead to lots of possible answers based on interpretation, I think it would be a matter of clear writing to mention the explicit definition here.)

Well, reassure the reader you have covered the obvious α =0 case, the Gaussian wavepacket, in class. You then have the expression for its translates in phase-space... Show your work.

Yes, $|\beta\rangle$ is a coherent state. I have edited the question to clarify.

The easiest way to go about this is by Fourier transforming (since the Hamiltonian looks so nice in the momentum picture). I'm going to ignore the explicit constants since I think it makes this easier to read.
The wavefunction of a coherent sate (i.e. our state at t=0) in position space is a Gaussian, so
Fourier transforming you get another Gaussian
\begin{align}
\tilde{\psi}(p) &= N \exp(-ap^2 + bp + c),
\end{align}
where $N$ is something that takes care of normalization. The Schrödinger equation for this Hamiltonian is
\begin{align}
i\frac{d}{dt}\tilde{\psi}(p,t) = \frac{p^2}{2}\tilde{\psi}(p,t) 
\end{align}
This is a standard first order differential equation, you can rearrange it
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\tilde{\psi}}{\tilde{\psi}} &= -i\frac{p^2}{2}\\
\frac{d}{dt}{\log\left(\tilde{\psi}\right)} &= -i\frac{p^2}{2}\\
\log\left(\tilde{\psi}\right)&= -i\frac{p^2}{2}t + C(p)\\
\tilde{\psi}(p,x) &= \exp\left(-i\frac{p^2}{2}t + C(p)\right),
\end{align}
Where $C$ is a function you can find since you know $\tilde{\psi}(p,0)$. In this case because everything is Gaussian you can easily Fourier transform back to obtain $\psi(x,t)$ or compute $\langle\beta|\psi(t)\rangle$ for some coherent (and thus Gaussian) $\beta$.

"a coherent sate (i.e. our state at t=0) in position space is a Gaussian" This statement taken at face value is simply not correct. The notion of a coherent state makes not statement about position space (spatiotemporal degrees of freedom) because a quantum state refers to the particle-number degrees of freedom. A better way to state it would be that a "coherent state is a Gaussian function of any quadrature variable".

@flippiefanus My answer is correct in the context of the quantum version of the simple harmonic oscillator. I guess you're talking about coherent states in some other context.

Then you should make it clear that your statement only applies for the quantum harmonic oscillator.

@flippiefanus I think that would be uneccessary for anyone who has read the question. We're talking about a system with kinetic energy given by $\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2}$, it doesn't really make sense to talk about any other context here.

Ors gave you the Schrödinger approach to this computation. If you want to keep up the Heisenberg point of view, you need to insert a completeness relation with respect to the momentum basis, as follows :
$$
\langle\beta|e^{-i\hat{H}t}|\alpha\rangle = \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}p\; \langle\beta|e^{-i\hat{p}^2t/2}|p\rangle\langle p|\alpha\rangle = \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}p\; e^{-ip^2t/2}\psi_\beta(p)^*\psi_\alpha(p),
$$
where $\psi_\alpha(p) = \langle p|\alpha\rangle$ denotes the momentum of wavefunction of the coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$, which corresponds to the Fourier transform of its position counterpart. Ultimately, you face a bulky gaussian integral.
